# Multi-threading using a share socket in Haskell

Tags: multithreading, sockets, haskell, tcp

In Haskell, can the same socket be shared between two threads?  Essentially, what I am trying to do is create a thread to write to a socket and another to read from the socket.

The read thread would be a loop that constantly wait, monitor and pick up any messages generated by the socket.

Another thread (the write thread) would send code to the socket.

Please advise.

Comment: It is allowed in C, why shouldn't this be allowed in Haskell? In Haskell all values are immutable, even.

Comment: What have you tried? As far as I know there shouldn't be any issue with that, you should just be able to do a normal `forkIO` and proceed as usual.

Comment: It may be worth noting that there are more sophisticated ways of communicating between Haskell threads than sending messages over a socket.  Depending on the application, simply using the `par` function or working with MVars or software transactional memory will generally be *much* more effective than some horrible, hand-crafted socket protocol.  I think the only case where you'd actually want this kind of socket-based design was if you were trying to simulate a network protocol.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is allowed.